# Cannot figure out how to include another package in a Github Pages Blazor deployment setup

Tags: c#, github, blazor, github-actions, github-pages

Before anything else: I realize I'm probably missing something stupid. But so far I have been all but completely unable to Google up a solution to this issue, as it seems to be an intersection of several problems that people normally seem to know how to deal with and so no notes on it seem to exist.

The core of the issue is that I have a Github repository with Blazor WASM in it, with an Action that compiles and deploys it into another branch, which is then used for Github Pages.

However, I'm having trouble getting it to add a NuGet package to the deployment, with it instead crashing out as if it can't see it.

I have been following [this](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-aspnet-blazor-webassembly-to-github-pages) guide on how to deploy Blazor onto Github Pages, mostly successfully. I then added NAudio to the project via the NuGet package manager built into Visual Studio, and started including it in the code via `using NAudio.Wave` and since then the action has been erroring out with this error here at the `Publish .Net Core Project` stage:

> The type or namespace name 'NAudio' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my current deployment script

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

# Run workflow on every push to the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  deploy-to-github-pages:
    # use ubuntu-latest image to run steps on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # uses GitHub's checkout action to checkout code form the master branch
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    # sets up .NET Core SDK
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.*
    # publishes Blazor project to the release-folder
    - name: Publish .NET Core Project
      run: dotnet publish Project-Biovocoder.csproj -c Release -o release --nologo
    # changes the base-tag in index.html from '/' to 'Project-Biovocoder' to match GitHub Pages repository subdirectory
    - name: Change base-tag in index.html from / to Project-Biovocoder
      run: sed -i 's/<base href="\/" \/>/<base href="\/Project-Biovocoder\/" \/>/g' release/wwwroot/index.html
    # add .nojekyll file to tell GitHub pages to not treat this as a Jekyll project. (Allow files and folders starting with an underscore)
    - name: Add .nojekyll file
      run: touch release/wwwroot/.nojekyll
    # publishes your static files to GitHub Pages
    - name: Commit wwwroot to GitHub Pages
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
      with:
        TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        BRANCH: gh-pages
        FOLDER: release/wwwroot
```

I have tried adding NAudio into the only file I could figure out had any relevancy to this issue, `_Imports.razor`, however it is very clearly not actually doing what I want it to do. And in every other area I looked at, it was already included.

I am currently at a near total loss when it comes how to find a solution to this problem, because it seems to be an intersection of me not quite knowing how *several* parts of this setup work, alongside Github Pages support for Blazor still being just a little bit jank.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently it was because for whatever reason my Visual Studio was adamantly REFUSING to update the actual project file with the added dependency until I forced it closed.

Because of *course* it would be something dumb like that.